# SQL Server single query takes longer by end of week

Tags: sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 R2.  We are reporting off a DB-Amp backup of our SalesForce instance.
I have a SQL query that takes about 8 seconds to run on Monday.  By Friday the duration is 31 seconds and my app is giving up a second too early.  By the next Monday, the query is performing quickly again.
[Here is the SQL](https://gist.github.com/3763315)
I don't have any Jobs running weekly that do any cleanup.  Rebuilding indexes and sp_syspolicy_purge_history are nightly jobs.
I checked Profiler and nothing else is happening while the query is running slowly.
I don't see any User Temp tables that were created before today (Friday).
I have another similar query that never slows down.
Any ideas?!

Comment: Best off capturing a slow and fast actual execution plan and seeing what the differences are.

Comment: No offense, but who was this written by ? *CASE WHEN (1=1  AND (00=11  OR 1=1  )  AND ...*

Comment: The SQL is actually modified quite a bit by my application.  Those are place holders for string substitution or so I don't have to add logic to decide if I should remove the first "AND".  
This specific SQL is always the primary execution from the first viewing.

Comment: Martin, I'll do that.  I've taken the capture today and will get another Monday.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the speedup this weekend?! 
However, I did find the AccountTeamRollup CTE was a huge drain.
I was able to remove the CTE and replace the referring 'Team' column with the below.  It went from 30sec to 4sec.

```
,STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + SUB.UserN AS [text()]
    FROM (
        Select distinct atm.AccountId, u.Name UserN
        From AccountTeamMember atm (nolock) 
            INNER JOIN [User] u  (nolock) 
                ON atm.UserId = u.Id) SUB
    WHERE SUB.AccountId = acct.Id
    FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '' ) Team
```